# Solve the following nonlinear programming problem using Lagrange multipliers: max $f(x, y)$ = $\sin(x) \cos(y)$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Tags: numerical-methods

Solve the following nonlinear programming problem using Lagrange multipliers:
max $f(x, y) = \sin(x) \cos(y)$
is subject to
$x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Defining
$$\begin{cases}f(x,y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) \\\\ g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1\end{cases}$$

We form the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y)$$

Now it's partial derivatives will be:

$$\begin{cases}\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial x} =\cos(x)\cos(y) - \lambda 2x\\\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial y} =-\sin(x)\sin(y) - \lambda 2y\\\displaystyle \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \lambda} =x^2+y^2-1\end{cases}$$

setting them to zero and using the two first to build linear combinations for the famous addition and subtraction formulae of cos

$$\cos(x+y) = \lambda(2x+2y)$$
$$\cos(x-y) = \lambda(2x-2y)$$
solving both separately for $\lambda$ gives us:
$$\lambda = \cos(x+y)/(2x+2y) = \cos(x-y)/(2x-2y)$$

$y=0$ gives solution for all $x$.,

But we must not forget last equation which gives $x^2=1 \Leftrightarrow x= \pm 1$

Now remember that Lagrange method will only provide necessary condition for global optimum but not sufficient. So we will need to do sanity check for our solutions. Check function values at points.

---

Another way we can approach this is by parameterization of the unit circle $$t\in [0,2\pi] \begin{cases}x(t) = \cos(t)\\y(t) = \sin(t)\end{cases}$$

This way we can write $$f(t) = \sin(\cos(t))\cos(\sin(t))$$

The chain and product rules of differentiation help us arrive at:

$$\frac{f(t)}{\partial t} = (-\sin(t) \cos(\cos(t))) \cos(\sin(t)) + \sin(\cos(t))(  -\cos(t)\sin(\sin(t)) ) $$

This expression is on the form $f_1(t)f_2(t)f_3(t) + g_1(t)g_2(t)g_3(t)$.

Also here we can find trivial zeroes wherever any logical combination of $f_i(t)=0, g_j(t)=0$.

We do notice that happens for $$\{\sin(t), \sin(\sin(t))\}, t=0,\pi$$

Which do correspond precisely to the points found with the Lagrangian.